# Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method(Batches)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a C# code for the database. I am getting the following error. Can somebody please help me out.

> Error: Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1955  Non-invocable member 'BatchEntities.Batches' cannot be
>   used like a method.   AddBatch    C:\Users\SA051263\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\AddBatch\AddBatch\Controllers\HomeController.cs 45  Active

**Code:**

```
    public HomeController()
    {
        _db = new BatchEntities();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData.Model = _db.Batches.ToList();
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Add(FormCollection form)
    {
        var batchToAdd = new Batch();

        // Deserialize (Include white list!)
        TryUpdateModel(batchToAdd, new string[] { "BatchName", "StartDate" }, form.ToValueProvider());

        // Validate
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(batchToAdd.BatchName))
            ModelState.AddModelError("Title", "Title is required!");

        // If valid, save movie to database
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            _db.Batches(batchToAdd);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        // Otherwise, reshow form
        return View(batchToAdd);
    }
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, that your trying to use a member as a member function.which you cant do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here -

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

    **_db.Batches(batchToAdd);**
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

`_db.Batches` is a property, (probably with signature `DbSet<Batch>`), not a function.

Try something like this -

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    **foreach(var b in batchToAdd){
        _db.Batches.Add(b);
    }**
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change _db.Batches(batchToAdd) to _db.Batches.Add(batchToAdd).

You are using a class member as a member function.